# VS2015 Multiple startup projects - prevent page showing

Tags: visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

I have recently had to reinstall my development machine so I'm unsure how I did this before.

A solution which I have currently has 3 projects that are needed for startup for debugging, this works fine, when I run the solution I get 3 pages open up in the browser which makes logical sense, however on my previous installation of my machine I only had one page open up, the API and MVC projects didn't show in the browser, but they were running so the entire application worked.

Is there a way to suppress the unneeded pages from opening up in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the option after a while, it was in the project properties, not the solution properties!

Here are the details if anyone is interested:

```
Right-click on the Project
Choose Properties 
Go to the Web tab 
In the Start Action section select the 'Don't open a page. 
    Wait for a request from an external application.' option.
```